# SISS - Check Null DerivedColumn

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, derived-column

Does someone knows how to check `IS Null` expression on SISS ?

IF columns is NULL > RETURN NULL , IF is NOT return value from column

*I am developing this on DerivedColumn.*

[image]

**FYI: The column is not always in my Excel layout, that is the reason that I have to check if that column exists or not.**

Comment: Checking whether a column is NULL is not the same as checking whether it exists.   Can you please word your question so that it is not ambiguous?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following expression:

```
(ISNULL([InputColumn]) || [InputColumn] == "") ? NULL(DT_STR,50,1252) : [InputColumn]
```

**References**

- [? : (Conditional) (SSIS Expression)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/expressions/conditional-ssis-expression?view=sql-server-2017)
- [ISNULL (SSIS Expression)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/expressions/isnull-ssis-expression?view=sql-server-2017)